# Merging two JSON Objects in Node-Red

Tags: json, node-red

I am having some trouble trying to merge two JSON objects retrieved from my SQL Server database into a single object in Node-Red.

The flow I have created is the following:
[image]

For each call to the database I am receiving the following objects:

Plans:

```
[{"PlanID":2,"Status":0,"EndTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}]
```

Goals:

```
[{"GoalID":1,"PlanID":2, "Type":2,"Message":"Walk 1000 km","Difficulty":0}]
```

I have created two functions which assign these objects into flow variables ('plans' and 'goals'), and now I was trying to merge both objects into a single JSON object.

I don't know if I have to use the Join node for this purpose and if so how to configure it, but my idea was to create a JSON object in this format:

```
[{"GoalID":1,"Plan":{"PlanID":2,"Status":0,"EndTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}, "Type":2,"Message":"Walk 1000 km","Difficulty":0}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I wouldn't set them as flow variables as these will get over written if you get a second request in to the http-in node while the Database look ups are happening. Better to add them as `msg` variables then they flow with the `msg` and can't be overwritten.

Given you are not just combining the 2 objects to get the super set of keys and values you are probably best off just using either a function node or the change to assemble to the output object yourself.

Assuming the input looks something like:

```
msg.plans = [{"PlanID":2,"Status":0,"EndTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}]
msg.goals = [{"GoalID":1,"PlanID":2, "Type":2,"Message":"Walk 1000 km","Difficulty":0}]
```

then the function node would look something like:

```
msg.payload = msg.goals[0];
msg.payload.plan = msg.plans[0];
delete msg.goals;
delete msg.plans;
return msg;
```

The change node rules would looks something like

[image]

The join node would work to get the 2 objects into an array or an object using the topics as keys to hold the 2 input messages.